# Get Generic method "Contains" With IgonreCase when Create Dynamic LambdaExression

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, lambda, dynamic-expression

I want to create dynamic Lambda Expression for Method Call **Contains** for list of string values,
the below code work's fine but not ignored string **Case Sensitive**

```cs
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(E), "x");
IQueryable<E> itemsToFilter = null; //this parameter set from input parameters
parameterName = "Name"; //this parameter set from input parameters
var prop = typeof(E).GetProperty(parameterName, BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
MemberExpression propertyExp=Expression.Property(param, parameterName);
var genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
IList tmplist = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
foreach (var obj in orcond.Values)
{
   tmplist.Add(obj);
}
methodin = tmplist.GetType().GetMethod("Contains");
var list = Expression.Constant(tmplist);
var containsMethodExpin = Expression.Call(list, methodin, propertyExp);
comparison = Expression.Lambda<Func<E, bool>>(containsMethodExpin, parameter)
itemsToFilter.Where(comparison);
```

> Note that the above code worked only for entity framework IQueryable but not worked for C# List

then I want to compare string in list with IgnoreCase

I want to call `Contains` with `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` but when I use

```cs
methodin = typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(IEqualityComparer<string>) });
```

'methodin' returns null
Please help how to get **Contains** with **IEqualityComparer** with correct reflection use.

Comment: First, the method that you're looking for is in `Enumerable`, not in `List`, since it's an extension method; second, you can't use `GetMethod` to get a method that has parameters of generic types, you need to filter the list yourself (in this case checking for `Name == "Contains"` and `GetParameters().Length == 3` would be enough)

Comment: @ferc Can you send me answer?
if I don't use generic then how i call method?

Answer (score 2):

To find the "Contains" method with the `EqualityComparer` parameter, you can do:

```
MethodInfo Method = null;

foreach (var m in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods())
{
    if (m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 3)
    {
        Method = m.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
var l = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
var Result = (bool)Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { l, "a", EqualityComparer<string>.Default });
```

Comment: Is there any better way?

Comment: I don't think there is. You could make it a bit more compact by using LINQ, and you could wrap it up in an extension method that returns the `MethodInfo` object... but the algorithm is going to be essentially the same 

Comment: I dont want to use foreach to get extention method and generic method
can you explain me a better way?\

Answer (score 1):

To invoke get the method with StringComparison just use

```cs
var property = "NameOfYourProperty"
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
var member = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
var method = typeof(string)
             .GetMethod("Contains", 
                 new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
```

Then create your constants

```cs
var textConstant = Expression.Constant(searchText, typeof(string));           
var ignoreCaseConst = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase,
                                     typeof(StringComparison));
```

And call

```cs
var call = Expression.Call(member, method, textConstant, ignoreCaseConst);
```